# Retrieve an input value from a node

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fancytree

I have this code:

```
<div id="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            ind impianto 1
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input id="crea1" name="crea1" type="text" placeholder="anno">
                    <button onClick="creaquestionario(1)">crea</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If I try to retrieve the value of input with `var anno=$('#crea1').val();` in the function `creaquestionario()` it return an empty string.
The declaration of tree is:

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
    keyboard: false,
    activate: function(event, data) {
        var node = data.node;
        if (node.data.href) {
            eval(node.data.href);
        }
    },
});
```

I want to create a button that call a function with a value of input and a value (the code is created in a php script)

Comment: because `<input id="crea1" name="crea1" type="text" placeholder="anno">` has no value.

Comment: No. it's not.. http://jsbin.com/xenoqo/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: where you set the value for the variable `crea1`?

Comment: user insert value in imput box and when click on button i want to retrieve te value insert

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (This code works for me, hope it helps)

```
// 1. Render hidden form fields 
$("#tree").fancytree("getTree").generateFormElements(true, false);

// 2. After this, you can access them using normal JQuery (i.e. select on class names or IDs). Shown here iterating all input elements,
$("input").each(function (index, element) {
  // do something with the input, read the value, whatever:
  var s = $(this).val();
})
```